# How to get all virtual products sku in configurable product particularly in view.phtml

Tags: magento2

I am using Magento2.2. I want to display all enabled child products SKUs in product page(view.phtml) of parent configurable product like

```
$SKU = $this->getProduct()->getSku();
```

Please give some tips to do it.

My View.phtml code

```
<?php
error_reporting(1);
    $_config = $this->helper('Sm\Theme\Helper\Data');
    $detailStyle = $_config->getProductDetail('detail_style');
    $thumsStyle = $_config->getProductDetail('thumbs_style');

    if($detailStyle == 'detail-1'){
        include (dirname(__FILE__).'/detail-style/detail-1.phtml');
    } else {
        include (dirname(__FILE__).'/detail-style/detail-sidebar.phtml');
    }
    $SKU = $this->getProduct()->getSku();

$product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_product');//get current product
$productTypeInstance = $product->getTypeInstance();
$usedProducts = $productTypeInstance->getUsedProducts($product);

//echo $product->getId(); //Main configurable product ID
//echo $product->getName(); //Main Configurable Name

foreach ($usedProducts  as $child) {
    echo $child->getSku()."</br>"; //Child Product Sku    
}

?>
```

Comment: Do you want to show all enabled only virtual product skus in single line comma seperated?

Comment: no may be in a separate array or using loops like this

$configurableProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(1); //here 1 is productId 
$childProducts = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->getUsedProducts(null,$configurableProduct);   
foreach($childProducts as $child) {
    echo $child->getSku();
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use below code and put in view.phtml file and print as per your requirement

```
    <?php
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_product');//get current product
    $productTypeInstance = $product->getTypeInstance();
    $usedProducts = $productTypeInstance->getUsedProducts($product);

    //echo $product->getId(); //Main configurable product ID
    //echo $product->getName(); //Main Configurable Name

    foreach ($usedProducts  as $child) {
        echo $child->getSku()."</br>"; //Child Product Sku    
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Thank you for the Reply. But it is not working. Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get() on null in /opt/lampp/htdocs/website/app/design/frontend/Sm/theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view.phtml:23

Comment: can you please share view.phtml code?

Comment: I have updated code. Please check

Comment: please try $PType = $this->getProduct()->getTypeId();
it will return type id and than you need to check $PType == 'simple' or like

Comment: Thank you sooooo much..... Thank you for your support.... I can get product type..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69094/discussion-between-meetanshi-and-tamil-selvan).